# Portable Gallio.Echo and the user cache

Tags: gallio

Is there a way to disable/redirect Gallio's plugin cache via Gallio.Echo (or a configuration file)?

I'm trying to keep my build portable and the cache is getting in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no. It uses LocalApplicationData and there's no way to change that, or even turn it off.

How does it prevent your build being portable?

Comment: It would prevent each build having their own copy of Gallio w/ any required plugins. Doing so right now fires up plugin conflict errors.

Comment: Interesting. It should just break the cache if the plugins have changed, could you raise an issue on googlecode please?

Comment: Will do (minimum 15 char limit be damned)